# In most physical cases, the elements of a group can be represented by unitary matrices. Why no time-reversal?

Tags: group-theory, time-reversal-symmetry

In Dresselhaus's [group theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540328971) page 19, a theorem writes:

> Every representation (of a Hamitonian's group) with matrices having non-vanishing 
>   determinants can be brought into unitary form by an similarity
>   transformation.

On page 21 writes:

> On the other hand, not all symmetry operations can be represented by
>   a unitary matrix; Time reversal operator is represented by an
>   anti-unitary matrix.

My question is, since time reversal operator represented by a matrix, which has the determinant of a non-zero value(?). Is this a contradiction?

Comment: where did you see that time reversal is implemented by a matrix? I think this is impossible - precisely because of the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this passage is not very good (By the way, here is an online version with slightly different paging: http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.734j/www/group-full02.pdf).

If you have a look at the proof, what they actually does is the following:

**Theorem:** Every representation of a finite group with matrices having non-vanishing determinants can be brought into unitary form.

I don't see how they can get rid of the finiteness assumption (unless he uses some sort of compactness/boundedness), so they should state this - it's at best sloppy. In particular, the counterexample of katz is then invalid, since the group of integers is clearly infinite.

Anyway, there are well-known theorems along these lines such as:

**Theorem:** Every representation of a finite group is unitarizable. (see e.g. [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=6V02ivlwC3AC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=finite%20group%20representation%20unitarizable&source=bl&ots=3_WtUSO_Zn&sig=1sU7gH31elA6-MoQx19altAsnGk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHtbaboeDJAhVFXRQKHeeADE0Q6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=finite%20group%20representation%20unitarizable&f=false))

**Theorem:** Every finite dimensional representation of a compact group is unitarizable. (follows from e.g. [here](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kisilv/courses/epal014.html))

However, when they speak about representations, they always mean linear representations. Which brings me to the time-reversal symmetry:

This is antiunitary and therefore in particular antilinear. It can therefore not be represented by a matrix - since a matrix represents by definition a linear operation. Therefore, the theorems don't apply.

Comment: @buzhidao: Right. I wanted to write "they" because I thought about the authors of the books, but you are right, I used "he" although I shouldn't. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The claim on page 19 seems incorrect without further clarification.  For example, the group of integers $n$ acting by $\begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ cannot be made unitary. Perhaps there are further restrictions on the group or on the action? Perhaps compact group, or action by Hermitian matrices?

Comment: maybe because your group is infinite. A physical system can't have infinite symmetries.

Answer (score 0):

The seemingly contradiction is from the fact that time-reversal operator can't represented by a matrix. It is a matrix times a conjugate operator, therefore talking about its determinant is meaningless.